# unable to format charts in vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, format, excel-charts

I have 18 charts and want to change their formatting, but the following code doesnt work

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cht As Chart

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects

cht.Activate
  
cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
    
Next cht
```

by the nature of errors, it appears to be a syntax mistake but i could not figure it our despite reading through multiple queries

Comment: What is the error, what line?  You are trying to put chartobjects in chart object, cht needs to be from chartobject.chart, so you need to loop "chartobjects" say `for each cho in ....` and in the loop `set cht=cho.chart`

Comment: The error says "Run-time error '13':Type mismatch". sorry I did not understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop the chart objects, then take the chart from those.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cho As ChartObject
Dim cht As Chart

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each cho In ws.ChartObjects

Set cht = cho.Chart

cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"

Next cho
```

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Many thanks.